# CSV Loading in HTML

Tags: html, csv

for some reason, the above "html" stopping read, the CSV file, not know, if missing something, this have working in past. Not know the reason for stop or what have been changing.

```html
<html>

<script>


 tdc = '<OBJECT ID="data" WIDTH="0" HEIGHT="0"'+ 
 ' CLASSID="CLSID:333C7BC4-460F-11D0-BC04-0080C7055A83">\n'+
 ' <PARAM NAME="DataURL" VALUE="shares.csv">\n'+
 ' <PARAM NAME="FieldDelim" VALUE=";">\n' +
 ' </OBJECT>\n' +
 '<div datasrc="#data" datafld="Text" dataformatas="HTML"></div>\n'; 

 document.write(tdc);

</script>

<body style="background-color:grey">

<Table width=1024px DATASRC=#data BORDER="0">
<THEAD style="font-family:verdana; font-size:10px;">
  <TH>SecurityGroup</TH>
  <TH>UNCPath</TH>
  <TH>Nome</TH>
</THEAD> 
<TR style="font-family:verdana; font-size:10px; background-color:white"> 
  <TD><SPAN DATAFLD="Column1"></SPAN></TD> 
  <TD><SPAN DATAFLD="Column2"></SPAN></TD> 
  <TD><SPAN DATAFLD="Column3"></SPAN></TD>
</TR> 
</TABLE>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's an ancient piece of code that works only on IE, which browser did you test it on?

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to use the [Tabular Data ActiveX control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/ms531358(v=vs.85)). This was only ever supported in Internet Explorer and, IIRC, is not supported in **current** versions of Internet Explorer.

A modern approach to displaying CSV data in HTML would be to programmatically convert it to an HTML table.

This could be done server-side in the programming language of your choice, or client-side using a combination of [Ajax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) to fetch the data, a CSV parser such as [Papa Parse](https://www.papaparse.com/) to convert it to a JavaScript data structure and [DOM manipulation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Introduction) to insert it into the page.

Answer (score -1):

Solved!
The script working at IE by adding the follow meta:

`<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8;FF=3;OtherUA=4" />`